# How can I grab a variable from another script without return it?

Tags: python, function, time

I'm setting up a script where 2 functions are defined. For example:

```py
def function1():
   start = time.time()
   dosomething()
   time1 = time.time() - start
   return A

def function2():
   print(time1)
   return B
```

I'm trying to import a variable from another function but on the same script.

I've tried to use a logger but it didn't find the way.

Comment: Why can't you return that variable in `function1` then pass it to `function2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `global` keyword.

```
import time
time1 = None
def function1():
   global time1
   start = time.time()
   time.sleep(0.4)
   time1 = time.time() - start
   return 10

def function2():
   print(time1)
   return 20
```

For instance:

```
function2()
#None
#20
function1()
#10
function2()
#0.40046191215515137
#20
```

Comment: sure it works, but not normally best practise to pollute the namespace like this

Comment: I agree. Very often the need of transfer local variables from a function to another is a symptom of bad design. Nonetheless, knowing that in python you can declare and modify global variables inside a function might be valuable.

Comment: `global` should be forbidden in my sense. No one should propose to use it.

Comment: @SvenKrüger You should talk with the python core team for that and proposing to remove the `global` keyword. The op asked "How can I grab a variable from another script without return it", and that's the purpose of this answer. Sure, you'd better return the variable, and I agree with you. But that's not the point in this question.

Comment: In fact, by doing this, my variable appears as not defined in my second function.